# I can´t concatenate a label with string in symfony3

Tags: string, symfony, label, concatenation, symfony-3.1

I can´t concatenate a label with string.

```
->add('originador', EntityType::class, array(
    'label' =>   "app.label.x_originador".'*',
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Usuario',
    'em' => $options['entityManager'],
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');    
    },
    'placeholder' => '',
    'required' => false,
))
```

In the part of `'label' =>   "app.label.x_originador".'*',` 
    I need that the result be `Originador*`,because the label is for required value.

The result that I recieve is `app.label.x_originador*`

Please, help me to get 
`Originador*` as  result.

Comment: Your label should already get the "required" css class, eg. `<label for="..." class="required">Your Text</label>` - so I'd simply append that asterisk to the css-class: `label.required::after { content: "*"; }`

Comment: Also, if it that field is required - why did you set `'required' => false` at the end of that element?

Comment: cause im coding all classes and im trying to work the label. Before put or change another things, I want recieve result of 'label' =>   "app.label.x_originador".'*', after that i will modify all app

Comment: As a follow-up comment, another way of solving your issue might be [Adding a "Required" Asterisk to Field Labels](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels) from the Symfony docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the translator service to your form type and translate then concatenate like this:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('originador', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' =>   $this->translator->trans('app.label.x_originador',[], 'domain').'*',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Usuario',
                'em' => $options['entityManager'],
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
                },
                'placeholder' => '',
                'required' => false,
            ));
        }
    }
```

juste replace "domain" with your translation domain.

EDIT: but yeah, the best solution is probably @ccKep's one

Comment: i have this error: Type error: Too few arguments to function AppBundle\Form\Type\Consulta3Type::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\Web\www\kybse\cis3\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 85 and exactly 1 expected

In   public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)